# How should I implement CRC for HDLC? (CRC16-CCITT)

Tags: crc

I need to implement CRC16-CCITT for HDLC, as part of developing some feature to control external HW (some type of LTE antenna).
The problem is that even though I have found many online implementations for CRC16-CCITT, the output values don't match the CRC values the HW vendor sent us.

For example, this is the first HDLC frame (named "Device Scan") which should be sent to the device, in hexadecimal format:
7EFFBF81F02A0113000000000000000000000000000000000000000313000000000000000000000000000000000000007F0F7E

As can be seen, the 7E in the start and end are the delimiters, and the last 4 hexadecimal characters are the CRC - which means 0x7F0F is the CRC result.

However, many online CRC calculators produce the result 0x6CC3
(take a look here for example: http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html  ,  https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation)

Same goes for another command, which is the matching "receive" command for the above.
the RCV command is: 
7E00BF81F018010F4B4D4B3032313941303035335A585806024B4D040130F1ED7E

which means that 0xF1ED is the CRC, and again it isn't what i see in other calculators, which produce 0xD814.

We have asked the vendor for clarifications, and he sent us this lookup table they are using:

crc table:
{
        0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
        0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
        0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
        0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
        0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
        0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
        0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
        0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
        0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
        0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
        0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
        0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
        0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
        0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
        0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
        0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
        0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
        0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
        0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
        0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
        0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
        0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
        0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
        0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
        0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
        0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
        0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
        0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
        0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
        0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
        0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
        0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78
}

This doesn't look like the regular table of CRC16-CCITT i found online, such as:

static const unsigned short CRC_CCITT_TABLE[256] =
{
    0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50A5, 0x60C6, 0x70E7,
    0x8108, 0x9129, 0xA14A, 0xB16B, 0xC18C, 0xD1AD, 0xE1CE, 0xF1EF,
    0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52B5, 0x4294, 0x72F7, 0x62D6,
    0x9339, 0x8318, 0xB37B, 0xA35A, 0xD3BD, 0xC39C, 0xF3FF, 0xE3DE,
    0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64E6, 0x74C7, 0x44A4, 0x5485,
    0xA56A, 0xB54B, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xE5EE, 0xF5CF, 0xC5AC, 0xD58D,
    0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76D7, 0x66F6, 0x5695, 0x46B4,
    0xB75B, 0xA77A, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xF7DF, 0xE7FE, 0xD79D, 0xC7BC,
    0x48C4, 0x58E5, 0x6886, 0x78A7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
    0xC9CC, 0xD9ED, 0xE98E, 0xF9AF, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xA90A, 0xB92B,
    0x5AF5, 0x4AD4, 0x7AB7, 0x6A96, 0x1A71, 0x0A50, 0x3A33, 0x2A12,
    0xDBFD, 0xCBDC, 0xFBBF, 0xEB9E, 0x9B79, 0x8B58, 0xBB3B, 0xAB1A,
    0x6CA6, 0x7C87, 0x4CE4, 0x5CC5, 0x2C22, 0x3C03, 0x0C60, 0x1C41,
    0xEDAE, 0xFD8F, 0xCDEC, 0xDDCD, 0xAD2A, 0xBD0B, 0x8D68, 0x9D49,
    0x7E97, 0x6EB6, 0x5ED5, 0x4EF4, 0x3E13, 0x2E32, 0x1E51, 0x0E70,
    0xFF9F, 0xEFBE, 0xDFDD, 0xCFFC, 0xBF1B, 0xAF3A, 0x9F59, 0x8F78,
    0x9188, 0x81A9, 0xB1CA, 0xA1EB, 0xD10C, 0xC12D, 0xF14E, 0xE16F,
    0x1080, 0x00A1, 0x30C2, 0x20E3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
    0x83B9, 0x9398, 0xA3FB, 0xB3DA, 0xC33D, 0xD31C, 0xE37F, 0xF35E,
    0x02B1, 0x1290, 0x22F3, 0x32D2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
    0xB5EA, 0xA5CB, 0x95A8, 0x8589, 0xF56E, 0xE54F, 0xD52C, 0xC50D,
    0x34E2, 0x24C3, 0x14A0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
    0xA7DB, 0xB7FA, 0x8799, 0x97B8, 0xE75F, 0xF77E, 0xC71D, 0xD73C,
    0x26D3, 0x36F2, 0x0691, 0x16B0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
    0xD94C, 0xC96D, 0xF90E, 0xE92F, 0x99C8, 0x89E9, 0xB98A, 0xA9AB,
    0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18C0, 0x08E1, 0x3882, 0x28A3,
    0xCB7D, 0xDB5C, 0xEB3F, 0xFB1E, 0x8BF9, 0x9BD8, 0xABBB, 0xBB9A,
    0x4A75, 0x5A54, 0x6A37, 0x7A16, 0x0AF1, 0x1AD0, 0x2AB3, 0x3A92,
    0xFD2E, 0xED0F, 0xDD6C, 0xCD4D, 0xBDAA, 0xAD8B, 0x9DE8, 0x8DC9,
    0x7C26, 0x6C07, 0x5C64, 0x4C45, 0x3CA2, 0x2C83, 0x1CE0, 0x0CC1,
    0xEF1F, 0xFF3E, 0xCF5D, 0xDF7C, 0xAF9B, 0xBFBA, 0x8FD9, 0x9FF8,
    0x6E17, 0x7E36, 0x4E55, 0x5E74, 0x2E93, 0x3EB2, 0x0ED1, 0x1EF0
};

i tried to use their table instead of mine, in our CRC implementation, but we still get different results than theirs.

Does anyone understand what is going on here?
which CRC is the actual correct HDLC CRC16-CCITT? 
What the the correct result of CRC16-CCITT for the above frames?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially thought the poly was 0x1189, but instead it's a bit reversal of 0x1021 = 0x8408, which is seen at table[0x80]. Using the online CRC calculator linked to below, it's the predefined CRC_X_25, poly = 0x1021, input reflected, result reflected, initial value 0xFFFF, final xor 0xFFFF. Click on "show reflected lookup table", and you will get the same table as the vendor's table when you calculate a CRC using the calculator.

When appending the CRC to data, the CRC is appended as lower byte, upper byte. So a CRC of 0xEDF1 is appended as: 0xF1, 0xED, and a CRC of 0x0F7F, is appended as: 0x7F, 0x0F.

Because the CRC is post complemented (xorout = 0xFFFF), if checking the CRC by recalculating it on data + CRC, if there are no errors, the CRC will be a non-zero constant, 0x0F47.

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

---

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

uint16_t crctbl[256];

void gentbl()
{
uint16_t crc, i, j;
    for(j = 0; j < 0x100; j++){
        crc = j;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            crc = (crc>>1)^((0-(crc&1))&0x8408);
        crctbl[j] = crc;
    }
}

uint16_t crc16(uint8_t * bfr, size_t size)
{
uint16_t crc = 0xffff;
    while (size--)
        crc = (crc>>8)^crctbl[(crc^*bfr++)&0xff];
    return(crc ^ 0xffff);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
uint16_t crc;
// bfr has 2 trailing zeroes to store crc into
uint8_t bfr[] = {0x00,0xBF,0x81,0xF0,0x18,0x01,0x0F,0x4B,
                 0x4D,0x4B,0x30,0x32,0x31,0x39,0x41,0x30,
                 0x30,0x35,0x33,0x5A,0x58,0x58,0x06,0x02,
                 0x4B,0x4D,0x04,0x01,0x30,0x00,0x00};
    gentbl();
    crc = crc16(bfr, sizeof(bfr)-2);
    std::cout << std::hex << crc << std::endl;
    bfr[sizeof(bfr)-2] = crc&0xff;
    bfr[sizeof(bfr)-1] = crc>>8;
    crc = crc16(bfr, sizeof(bfr));
    std::cout << std::hex << crc << std::endl;
    if(crc != 0xf47)
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer!
I entered the site, chose the custom CRC-16 with poly 0x1189 (along with initial value 0xFFFF and final xor value 0x0), but for the following data:

FFBF81F02A011300000000000000000000000000000000000000031300000000000000000000000000000000000000

the CRC result is 0x536A. however the vendor said the HW should respond to the "correct" CRC of value 0x7F0F.
How can i each this CRC value? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JonathanWeinreb - I updated my answer, it's not 0x1189, but instead a bit reflected 0x1021 = 0x8408.